# How to Randomly select n rows from pandas using group by multiple columns with min and max count from each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to get multiple output samples from the dataset.

[image]

And there are some constraints like min and max for each of the categories like,
need to select at least 3 and maximum 5 from each category and Type should be selected like Type=2&3 should have at least 2 values and maximum 3 and remaining types should be of at least 1. Should be taken on highest Priority column

Finally Sum of Credits_Remaining should not exceed some 'X' value. and need to generate multiple samples by setting a value ex: If select 10 then 10 different combinations of data should be prepared and save as csv.
I need to do this dynamically. Sample output
[image]

Like this I need 'N' number of output variation based on conditions.
Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: A sample of expected output would be helpful? Also any code you tried?

Comment: added sample output. I'm new to python and don't have any knowledge. Thank you

Comment: can you paste your input as text. image does not give us a way to capture the raw data for processing.

Comment: Hi Joe, I got this image from my friend....Currently I don't have any physical document to copy and paste. Sorry

Comment: Are you grouping by name? But looks like name is unique (like ID). Not sure about the data you are grouping on?